# PHP file_exists intermittently fails

Tags: php, iis-7

I have a PHP file checking to see if a file exists on the server using the file_exists function. Here's what I know:

- The path is relative to the PHP file and actually does exist, though PHP tells me it doesn't.
- file_exists works every time for an Administrator account, but fails intermittently (more than 90% of the time) for a user of the "Domain Users" group.
- The Domain Users group was temporarily granted full control of the directory where the files reside and the problem still exists.
- Both IUSR and IIS AppPool\AppPoolIdentifier have the appropriate access to the directory.
- PHP Safe mode is turned off

Running PHP version 5.2.6 and Windows Server 2008 r2 with IIS 7.

Why would file_exists intermittently fail for a non-Admin user group?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it _always_ exist? Race condition?

Comment: Yes, the file always exists. If I run the PHP file with an Admin account, file_exists always returns true. As a regular domain user, it returns false about 90% of the time, but occasionally returns true.

Comment: is this on the local disk or on a shared (network) disk? if on a local, sounds like a bug to me. If on a network, there might be some networking issues (either on the connectivity, winapi functions used or in the php implementation)

Comment: This is on a virtual server on a closed domain. We're thinking it could be a delay with the domain controller, but that's not something we have control over. PHP implementation should be fine, since this site was working fine until a few days ago.